# Bloquear acesso direto a um diretorio e criar condição para liberar acesso com .htacess

Tags: php, htaccess

Eu tenho isto para quando:

- Requisição não é um arquivo existente OU
- Requisição termina com .php

---

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://login/sites/?request=$1 [L]
```

Eu não entendo quase nada sobre htacess, alguém poderia me ajudar a, além de **bloquear** o acesso, **liberar** através de alguma condição, por exemplo via **GET**, ou melhir ainda via **$_SESSION**, o acesso a uma pasta?

**Ação:** Ao tentar acessar uma pasta, diretamente, ele seria redirecionado ao uma página de login e depois de efetuar esse login ele poderia acessar a pasta livremente através da url.

Comment: Ninguém????????

Comment: você quer liberar o acesso aos objetos contidos na pasta para um usuário específico, tipo ele pode fazer um request a uma determinada pagina php ou a um conjunto de páginas dentro de uma pasta, é isso?

Comment: Uma autenticação HTTP? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Comment: Isso! Antes eu bloqueio e depois libero com esse request!

Comment: @Lucas, autenticação HTTP com mod_ssl? Tipo eu tenho que mexer no terminal? Se for, não é isso.

Comment: Eu tive que usar o terminal para criar o arquivo de senhas. E foi sobre ssl sim

Comment: Sabe passar parametros PHP, via GET, para uma variável lá no htacess?

Comment: Acho que tem sim. Dá uma olhada aqui http://zenverse.net/capture-query-string-get-data-in-htaccess-rewrite/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal será ter um reencaminhamento para a página index.php, ou outra, que serve como uma página de entrada para o site.

Dentro dessa página deve ser colocada a lógica de validação. Se não existir $_SESSION definida quando o index.php é executado, faz-se o redirect para uma página de login.

No index.php podes ter algo do género:

```
$loginURL = "http://www.domain.tld/login.php"; // substituir por URL real
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
if (!isset($_SESSION['Login'])) {
  // redirecciona para páginda de login
  header("Location: {$loginURL}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olha vê se te ajuda, esse .htaccess daqui nós usamos no nosso FrameWork:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond public/$1 -F
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|public/)
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [QSA]
```

Ele faz o seguinte, tudo vai ser direcionado para index.php porem se for na /public e o arquivo existir, arquivo PHP não executa na /public, ele exibe, porem se o arquivo não existir ele executa o index.php

Comment: Queria uma condição para quando houver sessão. Tem como?